# Strength of electric field needed to observe noticeable effects on refraction in water

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-fields, refraction

I was looking into the mechanism behind refraction and stumbled upon a Fermilab video explaining it has to do with the electric fields of the particles in the medium interacting interacting with the electric field component of the incident light ray. I am wondering, if I were to do a physical experiment where I had a tub of water and a laser beam and then applied a voltage to the tub of water, how much voltage would be needed to see a noticeable effect on the angle of refraction? What are the corresponding equations to this scenario? And have I gotten something fundamentally wrong about this whole situation?

Answer (score 1):

Static electric field won't do much to refraction, refraction is a high-frequency process (visible light has terahertz frequencies) and the molecular electric fields can influence it because they themselves oscillate at that frequency.

If you make static electric field strong enough, water will polarize and get charged, and it will start ejecting droplets along lines of force of electric field.